# Prove that the highest power of $n$ contained in $(n^r-1)!$ is $\frac{n^r-nr+r-1}{n-1}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> > **Prove that the highest power of $n$ contained in $(n^r-1)!$ is $\frac{n^r-nr+r-1}{n-1}$.**

Attempt:
I want to use the following theorem:

> The largest exponent of $e$ of a prime $p$ such that $p^e$ is a divisor of $n!$ is given by $$e=[\frac{n}{p}]+[\frac{n}{p^2}]+[\frac{n}{p^3}]+\cdots$$.

The number of times the prime divisor $n$ is repeated in $(n^{r}-1)!$ equals the greatest exponent of $n$ contained in $(n^{r}-1)!$, which is 
$$ e=\left\lfloor\frac{n^{r}-1}{n}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n^{r}-1}{n^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n^{r}-1}{n^3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n^{r}-1}{n^4}\right\rfloor+\cdots+\left\lfloor\frac{{n^{r}-1}}{n^{r}}\right\rfloor
$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{r}\left\lfloor\frac{{n^{r}-1}}{n^{k}}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{r}n^{r-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{r}\left\lfloor-\frac{1}{n^k}\right\rfloor=\frac{n^{r}-1}{n-1}+r\times(-1)=\frac{n^r-nr+r-1}{n-1}$$.

Please suggest correct or wrong? Is there any alternative method to solve? Please suggest me in full.

Comment: Do you know that $n$ is a prime?

Comment: It's certainly not true in general $-$ take $n=6, r=2$ for a counter-example. Is it true if $n$ is a prime power?

Comment: @Arthur In the question in the book nothing mentioned. But the above theorem I have used in possible only if n is prime. Then???/??

Comment: Pleases suggest if n is prime.

Comment: Your calculations look good, in the case where $n$ is prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there any alternate way to solve?

Comment: I doubt that there is a significantly better way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Suggest me in details.

Comment: Speak me in complete English sentences.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would like to request you to suggest the significantly better way that you have mentioned in your last message in details.

Comment: I wrote, "I doubt that there is a significantly better way." That means that I don't think there is a significantly better way.